# Suitability Analysis using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, suitability-analysis

I want to do an overlay analysis to find most suitable locations to live in an area.

My criteria are road network, water lines, hospital locations, and schools. My steps are:

1. Convert all layers to raster using Rasterize
2. Apply Proximity (raster distance) tool
3. Apply Ordered Weighted Averaging tool to get the final map.

But it does not display the result due to the error: "The above files could not be opened, which probably indicates that they were not correctly produced by the executed algorithm." I tried this many times but result was same.

I want to know what the wrong with my method or if there is another Vector or Raster based method to perform this type of analysis using QGIS. I am using QGIS 2.2 Valmiera.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. Suitability analysis can be done in QGIS, but it is a long process. Do you have problem to use some of the QGIS tools for a given step, or do you want to know about the methodological issues related to suitability analysis?

Comment: Thankyou for providing more information.  However, I am keen to see your question become much more focussed.  It sounds like you are getting an error from the Ordered Weighted Averaging tool so I think you should provide some precise details of the parameters you are passing to it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.

The QGIS training manual actually features a very well written [tutorial on site selection](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/index.html).

Comment: Yes i have a problem when using Ordered Weighted Averaging SAGA tool to get the final suitability map from distance tasters it  give a error  "The following output layers could not be open Output raster layer" If know to correct please help me

Comment: @NethsiriJayaweera Have you looked at existing threads for these SAGA issues? If you have a new question, please open a new thread.